# How to combine 2 arrays in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a little bit problem.

I create data tables in my app and Im getting data from api, but from 2 endpoints.
First call returns me (e.g. offers):

```
{
 id: 1,
 product_id: 1,
 name: 'some name',
 etc...
}...
```

And the second one (eg. products):

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: 'some name',
 etc...
}...
```

And I wanna get this first array, but in product_id I want to put product name.

I created this:

```
const [offers, setOffers] = React.useState(null);
const [products, setProducts] = React.useState(null);

React.useEffect(() => {
 fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/offers`)
 .then((res) => res.json())
 .then((data) => {
  setOffers(data.data);
 });

 fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/products`)
 .then((res) => res.json())
 .then((data) => {
   setProducts(data.data);
 });
}, []);
```

But at this point I stopped and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your React code should probably look like this:

```js
const [offers, setOffers] = React.useState(null);
const [products, setProducts] = React.useState(null);

React.useEffect(() => {
 const promises = Promise.all([
   fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/offers`).then((res) => res.json()),
   fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/products`).then((res) => res.json())
 ]);
 promises.then((
   [offersResp, productsResp]
 ) => {
   const offers = offersResp.data;
   const products = productsResp.data;
   setProducts(products);
   return offers.map((offer) => {
     const product = products.find(pr => pr.id === offer.product_id);
     if(product) {
       return {
         ...offer,
         product_id: product.name
       }
     }
     return offer;
   })
 }).then(offers => {
   setOffers(offers);
 })
 .catch(err => {
   // don't forget to handle errors here
 });
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for fast solution. Thats works very well as I needed ;)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your products first and then setOffers

```
setOffers(offers.map((offer) => (
   {
    ...offer,
    product_name: products.find((product) => product.id == offer.product_id)?.name
   }
 )
))
```